# Laravel - Erro "TokenMismatchException" - Form?

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Por que o Laravel fica dando erro após submit do form, mesmo inserindo no form.

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Mesmo assim esta dando o `erro === TokenMismatchException`

- Localhost - xamp - W 7 32 bts - PHP 7.2.0 no ambiente windows
- Composer version 1.5.1
- laravel/framework (v5.4.36)

Comment: O Post é para o mesmo domínio ou para outra aplicação sua? Poderia explicar melhor o cenário e o que você está fazendo?

Comment: @Leandro Angelo É para o mesmo dominio,  o controller e o view correspondente estão na pasta ,  no momento estou rodando em localhost

Comment: Inclua a parte relevante do seu código, o post é feito via Javascript, você verificou se o header do request apresenta o token válido?

Comment: @Leandro Angelo Controler -- https://pastebin.com/D13y1ga3

Comment: @Leandro Angelo  Form  --  https://pastebin.com/919YmgSw

Comment: @Leandro Angelo ROTA --- Route::post('/register/step1', 'Auth\RegisterController@register_step1');